# ASP.NET Web Services and handling packet loss

Tags: asp.net, web-services, soap

I was wondering if someone could discuss some methods of possibly handling packet loss between a .NET WinForms application and our ASP.NET Web Services.  Currently we have sales people who use our software that are going over 4G or 3G air cards and the application has problems occasionally, if they don't have full bars.

I can think of two hypothetical ways to handle this, but not really sure how to implement the first one (assuming it's even possible):

Can HTTP resuming be used somehow to resume an HTTP call?

What about handling an exception and re-issuing the web service call X number of times?  Unfortunately I'm not sure what exception they're getting.  I've done a fair amount of testing with their air cards and I don't get the errors that they get when they're on the road.

Also, is there some sort of tool that can be used to simulate packet loss?  This would make testing a lot easier.

Thanks
-Adam

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) which is a great tool to find packet loss and re-transmissions and also lot other problems pertaining to packets. You can get some good starting guide videos from YouTube too.